# Using cell width and colspan

Tags: html, html-table, cell

Trying to understand why the third row is not adjusting correctly. It does adjust correctly when the colspan is set to 1 (instead of 2).

```
<table border="1" style="width:3in;">
     <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td colspan="3">123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:0.5in;" colspan="2" >12</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't have special powers, this is all I can see from what you shared. http://jsbin.com/viqoze/1/edit . Can you do better in explaining what's wrong?

Comment: [I think it is perfect](http://jsbin.com/tezekutepona/1/edit).

Comment: The third row's first 2 columns should be 0.5in (total). But they're not. The table is not adjusting the size accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that despite the simplicity of the case, it exceeds browsers’ capabilities in implementing the width settings. As a workaround, instead of setting width on a cell that occupies two columns, set the widths on those columns directly. Unfortunately this means that you need to make the division of the 0.5in width into parts fixed. To divide it evenly, add the following tags after the `<table ...>` tag:

```
<col style="width: 0.25in">
<col style="width: 0.25in">
<col>
```